# CSS - Confusion using the :hover method with images

Tags: css, hover, image

I'm confused about proper practice when using the :hover method in CSS. In this example, I have a photo that upon hover, changes to a different photo. As I understand, there are two options though I'm unclear how to accomplish either, and which one is optimum.

**Option 1:**

I have two images in my HTML. In this example, should I be positioning them in the exact same spot and then hiding one on hover?

http://jsfiddle.net/C5bKZ/4/

**Option 2:**

I create a single empty div in my HTML, and the use CSS to add a background-image, and then have a new background-image float over on hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/C5bKZ/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous ways you can accomplish this:

1. Sliding background: You could have a single image (with two images side by side) as the background and simply re-position it when the parent element is hovered.
2. Position the two images absolutely, one on top of the other, and hide the top one when you mouse over, thus revealing the second.
3. Place both images side-by-side in the parent, setting overflow to hitten (to hide the second image). When the user mouses over the parent, hide the first, which moves the second into view.

With the first example you posted, you could add the following CSS:

```
.image {
    width:    180px;
    height:   270px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image:hover :first-child {
    display:  none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/C5bKZ/10/

Answer (score 2):

Your options are both feasible, but in terms of optimum performance, I would do this is if it was possible:

1. Make one image that had both images in it one on top of the other.
2. Use a container element with the dimensions of one image only. (i.e. half the height of this new image)
3. Then on `:hover` change the `background-position`

This technique is called spriting / sprites.

The benefits are:

- you only have one image
- browser needs to make only 1 http request
- there is no delay between mouseover and the next image loading.

Comment: Wow sounds interesting. Does it matter if the two images are one on top of the other, or right beside each other?

Comment: No, doesn't really matter. Depends on your situation. If the container is a fixed width and height then either way is fine.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to implement option 1 would be like:

```
<a href="#" class="myLink"><img src="img1.jpg" class="img_on" /><img src="img2.jpg" class="img_off" /></a>
```

then the css would look like this:

```
.img_off, .myLink:hover .img_on{display:none;}
.myLink:hover .img_off{display:block;}
```

For the second option the issues is that on first hover there is always a minor flicker as the image has not been loaded.

I also find that first option is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a little more manageable by adding in a hover selector like this with a class for the initially hidden item:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://teamcoding.ca/leisure/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/373036_320675657996371_1880708219_n.jpeg"   id="image1"/>
    <img class="hover" src="http://teamcoding.ca/leisure/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/373040_295769990493061_127804360_n.jpeg"/>
</div>
```

​
**CSS**

```
.image { display: inline; }
.image img.hover { display:none; }
.image:hover img { display:none; }
.image:hover img.hover { display:inline; }
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/ZHNDU/